# Magento 2 : After upgrade some texts are coming in other language

Tags: magento2

I upgraded Magento from version 2.1.0 to 2.1.8.

After the upgrade some of the text are coming in French even though the language is set to English, both frontend and backend.

Answer (score 0):

Try these steps, making sure to **flush cache and/or reindex** when necessary:

1. Go to Stores>Configuration>General>Locale options, confirm English is selected, save config.
2. If the above step didn't fix it, go to System>All Users, click on the user that you are using to test the store frontend, and confirm that Interface Locale is also set to English.
3. If that also didn't work after you made sure that the indexes and caches are fine, double-check the language package to make sure that it still contains the dictionary (not just a stub). The dictionary CSV file(s), e.g. `/[module_name]/i18n/en_US.csv` have to be included where relevant in your Magento website's active module(s)/theme.
4. Lastly, if you confirm that the dictionary CSVs are in fact populated within the relevant modules/theme, note that the admin configuration `[*] Use Website`" does not refer to a visitor's web browser. It refers to the Website configured in the `Website - Store - Store View` hierarchy. To override that setting in a store view, confirm the box for `[ ] Use Website` is unchecked.

More info: http://imaginaerum.github.io/magento2-language-fr-fr/en.html